Computing Jacobian determinant of composite non-holomorphic function
For holomorphic functions, the Jacobian determinant of the composition $f \circ g$ of two functions is the product of their Jacobian determinants. Is there a similar way to compute Jacobian determinants of non-holomorphic functions? More specifically, I need to compute the Jacobian determinant of a composite function $f_1 \circ \dots \circ f_n$ where the Jacobians of the $f_i$ are triangular, so the individual determinants are efficient to compute and I'm looking for an efficient way to compute the Jacobian determinant of the composite function.

It depends on what you mean by the Jacobian. If your functions are smooth and you mean their Jacobians in the smooth sense (so over $\mathbb{R}$ rather than over $\mathbb{C}$) then the Jacobian of the composite is still the product of the Jacobians, this is the multivariate chain rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Multivariable_case

I mean the complex Jacobian (as it is defined for holomorphic functions). The real Jacobian of a complex function just gives me the abs squared of the complex Jacobian.

You seem to be mixing up the Jacobian and the Jacobian determinant. I mean you compute the entire Jacobian matrix, over $\mathbb{R}$. Why are you computing the complex Jacobian of functions that are not holomorphic?

No there is none, even if the (complex) dimension is $1$. More precisely, let
$$\partial:=\frac12\left(\frac\partial{\partial x}-{\rm i}\frac\partial{\partial y}\right).$$
If $f,g:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ are $C^1$ as maps from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^2$, but not holomorphic, then there is no way to compute the function $\partial(f\circ g)$ from $\partial f$ and $\partial g$. For instance if $f(z)=g(z)=\overline z$ then $\partial f=\partial g=0$ and $\partial(f\circ g)=1.$

Thank you. Is there maybe a way if additionally some other quantity is computed for f and g, that can be computed for the composite function based on the quantity and the jacobian determinant?

Yes of course: $\overline\partial:=\frac12\left(\frac\partial{\partial x}+{\rm i}\frac\partial{\partial y}\right)$. But then, doing what you describe amounts to composing the Jacobians over $\Bbb R$, by the usual chain rule.

No, I meant if there is a way to compute a set of quantities for f and g that are easy to compute for triangular matrices and allow to compute that set of quantities for $f\circ g$ where one of this quantities should be the Jacobian determinant I want to compute.

I don't get you. Your post says that your "triangular matrices" are the (complex) Jacobians (not the functions themselves, right?). So in dimension $1$, they are just the $1\times1$ matrices $\partial f$, $\partial g$, $\partial(f\circ g)$. The "set of quantities" I propose is $(\partial,\overline\partial)$.

Sorry, my last post was poorly worded. Yes, my triangular matrices are the complex Jacobians (and I'm looking for additional qunatities that are also efficient to compute for functions of many parameters and can help me get the complex Jacobian of the composite function (and to compute those additional quantities for the composite functions to compute the complex Jacobian of a composition of a large number of high-dimensional functions efficiently).
